# Hadoop MapReduce2 Optimization in Heterogeneous Cluster

Tags: hadoop, optimization, mapreduce

I have this configuration:

- Hadoop: **v2.7.1** (Yarn)
- An input file: Size = 100 GB.
- 3 Slaves: each has 4 VCORES with Speed = 2 GHz and RAM = 8 GB
- 5 Slaves: each has 2 VCORES with Speed = 1 GHz and RAM = 2 GB
- MapReduce program: WordCount

How can I minimize WordCount execution time by assigning small input splits to the 5 slower slaves and big input splits to the 3 fastest slaves?

Answer (score 2):

For each machine you can determine number of map/reduce slots, so if you want to send less workload to the slower machines you can define, for example 2 map/reduce task slots for each slower machine and 4  map/reduce task slot for each of the fast machines. This way you can control how much work load each different node in the cluster receives.

Comment: I wonder why YARN doesn't support VCORE SPEED in container configuration!